# Convert a Gridview to a Word Document

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ms-word

I am trying to convert a Gridview to a Word Document.

I keep getting an error in line:

```
GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
```

It states

```
Control 'MainContent_GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

Code:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>


Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim connStr, cmdStr As String
    connStr = "connectionstring works"
    cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM test;"
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    dt = ds.Tables(0)
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
                conn.Close()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.doc")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    GridView1.AllowPaging = False
    GridView1.DataBind()
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the gridview in between `<form runat="server">...</form>` tags